# Error: name 'band' not defined

Tags: python

I just wrote this code out and it worked roughly 30 minutes ago
after copying and pasting it onto my jupyter notebook cell, it doesn't seem to work.

I keep getting an error that name `band` is not defined with it clearly is in the `__init__`.

Where did I mess up?

```
import lyricwikia

x = 'Dragonforce'
y = 'Through the fire and flames'

class CatchLyrics:

    def __init__(self, band, song):
        self.band = band
        self.song = song

    def getLyrics(self):

        lyric = lyricwikia.get_lyrics(band, song)

        return lyric

d = CatchLyrics(x, y)

print(d.getLyrics())
```

Comment: Band is not defined here: `lyric = lyricwikia.get_lyrics(band, song)`.  Did you mean `self.band`?

Comment: Does `CatchLyrics` do anything else that justifies defining a class instead of a function? In fact, the function itself is just an alias for `lyricwikia.get_lyrics`; you could just write `from lyricwikia import get_lyrics as catch_lyrics`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the method:

```
def getLyrics(self):

    lyric = lyricwikia.get_lyrics(self.band, self.song)

    return lyric
```

You need to prepend `self.` to the object's attributes, otherwise the interpreter would look for local variables `band` and `song`, and will find none.